# UIViewRepresentable wrapped UIKit Map jumps back on moving

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw routes on a map and I had to come to the conclusion that this is not yet possible with SwiftUI. Many tutorials suggested wrapping the old `MKMapVIew` into a `UIViewRepresentable` which seems to work fine but I have one problem.

Because I need to be able to change the region from outside, I've added this line into the `updateUIView` method but this causes issues when I'm moving the map. I think what happens is when I scroll the map it updates the state but it does not do it for all the frames of the movements so when this updated region 'comes back' through the `updateUIView` method, my map is already in an other position so it jumps back.

How can I only update the region when it is intended?

Here is my code:

```
struct CustomMap: UIViewRepresentable{
    typealias UIViewType = MKMapView
    
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    var onMapTaped: ((_ item: MKMapItem) -> Void)?
    
    private let mapview: MKMapView = MKMapView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        mapview.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        mapview.showsUserLocation = true
        mapview.addGestureRecognizer(context.coordinator.tapRecognizer)
        
        
        return mapview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        return MapViewCoordinator(customMapView: self)
    }
    
    
    class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate{
        let customMapView: CustomMap
        var tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        
        
        init(customMapView: CustomMap){
            self.customMapView = customMapView
            super.init()
            self.tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(tapOnMap))
        }
        
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.customMapView.region = mapView.region
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62857024/12299030?

Comment: Not exactly because I need to update the map at any point, but I got an idea from it  so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No the most elegant solution in my opinion but it seems like there is no better one at the time. I got the inspiration from @Asperi's comment.
I passed a closure to the initializer of my view that accepts an `MKMapView` . I save that map view in my state so I can update the region on a button tap or whenever I want.